# Make button disappear from 3 seconds then reappear (swift3)

Tags: ios, button, swift3, timer, hidden

Every time I hit the button I would like the button to be hidden for 3 seconds then after the 3 seconds are up I would like the button to not be hidden.

```
@IBOutlet var save: UIButton!
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Comment: so what's the problem? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Sam Burns Google Timer in swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just schedule a closure to be executed on the main thread with a 3second delay that unhides your button.

```
@IBOutlet var save: UIButton!
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    save.isHidden = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3, execute: {
        save.isHidden = false
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CGD:

```
@IBOutlet var save: UIButton!
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    self.button.alpha = 0.0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        self.button.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

or you can use `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)`

```
@IBOutlet var save: UIButton!
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    self.button.alpha = 0.0
    perform(#selector(showButton), with: nil, afterDelay: 3)
}

@objc func showButton() {
    self.button.alpha = 1.0
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `perform(_:with:afterDelay)`. It's very limited compared to `DispatchQueue asyncAfter`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you use Google, you will find a lot of examples. Use something like this:

```
var timer: Timer!
@IBOutlet var save: UIButton!
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    save.isHidden = true
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func runTimedCode() {
    save.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Why are you invalidating the timer immediately?

Comment: Hm. You mean that ivalidate will disable timer before it finished?

Comment: Of course. That's what `invalidate` is for. And where do you hide the button?

Comment: There is no need to invalidate the timer at all. It's non-repeating. There's nothing to invalidate once the selector is called.